# How to remove values from a Python array, perform an operation on them and then replace them in the original array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I'm working with a huge dataset. What I want to do is take all values > 0 from the array and place them in a new array, run statistics on those extracted values and then place the new values back in the original array.

Suppose I have an array `[0,0,0,0,0, . . . .32, .44,0,0,0]` (i.e. the object `arr` in the script below): I want to remove the values such as .32, .44, etc., and put them in a new array `arr2`.

Then I want to do a statistical analysis (PCA) on this second array, take the new values corresponding with the original position in the original array and replace the original values with these new values. I've started coding this below, but have no idea how to extract values > 0 while maintaining the position in the array.

```
import os
import nibabel as nb
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as npl
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
#from dipy.io.image import load_nifti, save_nifti

np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)
FA = './all_FA_skeletonised.nii'

from dipy.io.image import load_nifti
img = nib.load(FA)
data = img.get_data()
data.shape        #get x,y,z and subject # parameters from image

#place subject number into a variable
vol_shape = data.shape[:-1] # x,y,z coordinates
n_vols = data.shape[-1]   # 28 subjects volumes

# N is the num of voxels (dimensions) in a volume
N = np.prod(vol_shape)

#- Reshape first dimension of whole image data array to N, and take
#- transpose
arr2 = []
arr = data.reshape(N, n_vols).T  # 28 X 7,200,000 array
for a in array:
    if a > 0:
        arr2.append(a)

row_means = np.outer(np.mean(arr2, axis=1), np.ones(N))
X = arr2 - row_means # mean center data array

#- Calculate unscaled covariance matrix of X
unscaled_covariance = X.dot(X.T)
unscaled_covariance.shape

# Calculate U, S, VT with SVD on unscaled covariance matrix
U, S, VT = npl.svd(unscaled_covariance)
#- Use subplots to make axes to plot first 10 principal component
#- vectors
#- Plot one component vector per sub-plot.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(10, 1)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(U[:, i])

#- Calculate scalar projections for projecting X onto U
#- Put results into array C.
C = U.T.dot(X)

***#- Put values in C back into original data matrix***
```

Comment: What about `extracted = arr[arr > 0]; # Doing PCA here; arr[arr > 0] = new_values`? Note that it might require manual reshaping because `arr[arr > 0]` will flatten the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the wanted values with their positions (in the original array) and store them in a dictionary as `index_in_the_original_array: value_in_the_original_array`. Then I would do the calculations on the `values` in the dictionary. Finally, we have the indices preserved (as keys in the dictionary) for replacing the values back in the original array. In code:

```
from pprint import pprint

original_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Collecting all values & indices of the elements that are greater than 5:
my_dictionary = {index: value for index, value in enumerate(original_array) if value > 5}
pprint(original_array)      # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
pprint(my_dictionary)       # {5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10}

# doing the processing (Here just incrementing the values by 2):
my_dictionary = {key: my_dictionary[key] + 2 for key in my_dictionary.keys()}
pprint(my_dictionary)       # {5: 8, 6: 9, 7: 10, 8: 11, 9: 12}

# Replacing the new values into the original array:
for key in my_dictionary.keys():
    original_array[key] = my_dictionary[key]

pprint(original_array)      # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

**Update**

If we want to avoid the use of a dictionary, we could do the following which does basically the same as above.

```
import numpy as np

def process_data(data):
    return data * 5

original_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
new_array = np.array([[index, value] for index, value in enumerate(original_array) if value > 5])
print(new_array)    # [[ 5  6]
                    #  [ 6  7]
                    #  [ 7  8]
                    #  [ 8  9]
                    #  [ 9 10]]

# doing the processing (Here, just using the above function that multiplies the values by 5):
new_array[:, 1] = process_data(new_array[:, 1])
print(new_array)    # [[ 5 30]
                    #  [ 6 35]
                    #  [ 7 40]
                    #  [ 8 45]
                    #  [ 9 50]]

# Replacing the new values into the original array:
for indx, val in new_array:
    original_array[indx] = val

print(original_array)  # [ 1  2  3  4  5 30 35 40 45 50]
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  I may have questions as I work through this, but it seems relatively straight forward.

Comment: I'm getting the following error message for the first line: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"  I'm not sure where I should be including the .any() in my code.  I tried it after "value" in the expression "if value > 5}" to no avail.  Any suggestions? --- SCRATCH THAT: I got it to work.

Comment: Okay, I guess I didn't solve the problem.  The line of code that ends with "if value > 5}" does not work in my case because python thinks that I want to know if there are any or all values greater than 5 (0 in my case).  How do I specify that I want to put values that exceed the threshold into the dictionary?

Comment: The basic idea of the solution is to preserve the positions along with the values and to use the positions to update the original array later. So it would be possible to implement the code with different data structures. Instead of a dictionary, a 2D array (numpy) could be used: say the first column for the original positions and the second column for values. I have assumed that you are quite familiar with numpy. So it should be easier for you. In short, keeping the basic idea unchanged, use a data structure that is the most efficient and suitable for you.

Comment: The answer has been updated to include a sample that does not use a dictionary to store the values and indices.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: @DartmouthDude82, please look into the comment section of [@Xiaowen Feng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091659/how-to-remove-values-from-a-python-array-perform-an-operation-on-them-and-then/45091860#45091860). There he mentions about `numpy.place`. I did not know about it. It seems a very easy and efficient way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** got the question wrong (see comments) so here's an update.

Say we have `a=[0,0,1,2,0,3]` and `b=[.1, .1, .1]` and want to combine them to get a `[0, 0,.1, .1, 0, 0.1]`, i.e. 0 remains at same indexes and all the other values get substituted:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([.1, .1, .1])
a = np.array([0,0,1,2,0,3], dtype='float64')  # expects same dtype
np.place(a, a>0, b)  # modify in place
```

Backup `a` before the `np.place` line if you need its original values.

---

previous version:

Not sure whether I got you right, assuming by 'maintaining the position in the array', you mean for example [0,0,1,2,0,3,0] should eval [1,2,3] (instead of [1,3,2] or something else). You can do this by `a[a!=]` where `a` is your array. If you only want to knock off leading/trailing zeros, try `numpy.trim_zeros` instead.

Things should be different if input is 2D arrays or matrices, as you'll need to keep them in shape.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Xiaowen, what I mean by "maintaining the position . . ." is that when I replace the values in the original array, I need the zeros to be back where they were in addition to the new values in the position the original value they are replacing was.  So say I started with [0,0,1,0,2,3] and now 1 = .78, 2 = .91, and 3 = .45, I need the new array to look like [0,0,.78,0,.91,.45].  Does that help?

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 then maybe you want to try `numpy.place()`. Say `a=np.array([0,0,1,0,2,3], dtype='float64')`, `b=np.array([0.78, 0.91,0.45])`, `np.place(a, a>0, b)` will modify `a` in place. Note the function expects same dtype for `a` and `b`. [docs for np.place](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html)

Comment: @XiaowenFeng, please update your answer to include the much simpler and elegant way to solve the problem. As I'm not very familiar with `numpy`, I did not know about `numpy.place()`. This (the comment above) is obviously a better option since there is no need to store the positions and thus no wastage of memory.

Comment: @XiaowenFeng, since `place()` has no idea about the locations of the elements to be updated, it would walk through all the elements and check the condition and then replace them and there should also be some kind of 'pointer' denoting the last element used from new_array, right? If so it would be computationally costlier than my answer. Whereas  I have all the locations & updated values in a dictionary for the final step. It just has to go to the particular locations and replace them. So my answer should be computationally faster though more memory consumption for the positions. Am I correct?

Comment: @arif I think `if value > 5` also need to walk through the input array (say `len(a)`), for list comprehensions are nested loops written short. `numpy` arrays are better indexed/organised than python's built-in list do, so most of the time you may want to utilise their class methods e.g. `np.dot(x, y)` usually does a better job than handmade loops, when `x` and `y` came big enough. Had `a=np.random.rand(10**5)` & execution for 20 times as a test, `np.place` was about 1000x faster (0.0018s vs1.55s) and memory cost was good.

Comment: But `if value > 5` has to be checked here twice. Once for extracting the values to be used as an operand of some calculations and then again while `place()` will be processed. While replacing the old values, I don't need to check that condition again since I already have all the positions. And for `place()`, if I have only 5 elements to be replaced in an array of 1K length, it has to walk through all 1K elements. But if I have the dictionary, I just have 5 positions to look up the array and replace. Whatever... I think I should learn more about `numpy` before talking about its performance.

Comment: @arif My thinking is that in your solution, there's a walk through loop to build the dictionary (check each value & save it to dict if >5). `np.place` should be generally working in the same way (checking, indexing, followed by replacing) because python can't tell whether a value at an arbitrary index is larger than 5 without execute a comparison. Main part of `np.place` is [written in C (`arr_insert `)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/77ff3d69dfc1d7f2410ff373900c467d829863b2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c) which I had no experience with, so can't tell how it outperforms.